# Couldn't match expected type `(t1, t2, t0)' with actual type `[a0]`

Tags: haskell, types, tuples, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to solve a fractional knapsack problem with the input,

```
[("label 1", value, weight), ("label 2", value, weight), ...]
```

and the output,

```
[("label 1", value, solution_weight), ("label 2", value, solution_weight), ...]
```

but I keep getting the error in `computeKnapsack`:

```
"Couldn't match expected type `(t1, t2, t0)' with actual type `[a0]`"
```

I can't understand what the problem might be. I'm trying to create a list of 3-entry tuples. How can I get it to stop expecting a single 3-entry tuple?

```
fst3 (a,b,c) = a
snd3 (a,b,c) = b
trd3 (a,b,c) = c
fst4 (a,b,c,d) = a
snd4 (a,b,c,d) = b
trd4 (a,b,c,d) = c
qud4 (a,b,c,d) = d

sortFrac (a1, b1, c1, d1) (a2, b2, c2, d2)
  | d1 > d2 = GT
  | d1 <= d2 = LT

fracKnap (x:xs) =
    fractionalKnapsack (x:xs) []

fractionalKnapsack (x:xs) fracList =
    if length (x:xs) <= 1
        then computeKnapsack (sortBy sortFrac (((fst3 x),(snd3 x),(trd3 x),(snd3 x) / (trd3 x)):fracList)) 100
        else fractionalKnapsack xs (((fst3 x),(snd3 x),(trd3 x),(snd3 x) / (trd3 x)):fracList)

computeKnapsack (x:xs) weightLeft =
    if length (x:xs) <= 1
        then (fst4 x, snd4 x, ((floor (weightLeft / (qud4 x)))*(qud4 x)))
        else (fst4 x, snd4 x, ((floor (weightLeft / (qud4 x)))*(qud4 x))):(computeKnapsack xs (weightLeft-(floor (weightLeft / (qud4 x))*(qud4 x))))
```

Comment: Please _do_ rewrite it without those ugly `fst` `snd` `trd` `qud` functions, it really makes it hard to understand what's going on. There has to be some sort of meaning to each tuple entry, describe it as a record type (`data KnapsackItem = KnapsackItem { propA :: Foo, propB :: Bar, propC :: Quu }`)

Comment: It is really hard to tell what the 4-tuple is supposed to represent, making it really hard to follow your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `then` branch of `computeKnapsack` the result is a single 3-tuple, but in the `else` branch it is a list of 3-tuples.

---

I'm going to rewrite `computeKnapsack` for you. I'll start with your version with the error fixed:

```
computeKnapsack (x:xs) weightLeft =
    if length (x:xs) <= 1
        then [(fst4 x, snd4 x, ((floor (weightLeft / (qud4 x)))*(qud4 x)))]
        else  (fst4 x, snd4 x, ((floor (weightLeft / (qud4 x)))*(qud4 x))) : (computeKnapsack xs (weightLeft-(floor (weightLeft / (qud4 x))*(qud4 x))))
```

First, I'm going to say what happens if the first argument to `computeKnapsack` is the empty list:

```
computeKnapsack []     _          = []
computeKnapsack (x:xs) weightLeft =
    (fst4 x, snd4 x, ((floor (weightLeft / (qud4 x)))*(qud4 x))) : (computeKnapsack xs (weightLeft-(floor (weightLeft / (qud4 x))*(qud4 x))))
```

It enables us to get rid of the `if`-test, making the code shorter overall and easier to understand.

Next, I'll deconstruct `x`:

```
computeKnapsack []             _          = []
computeKnapsack ((a,b,_,d):xs) weightLeft =
    (a, b, ((floor (weightLeft / d))*d)) : (computeKnapsack xs (weightLeft-(floor (weightLeft / d)*d)))
```

You might prefer to follow leftaroundabout's suggestion to create a record type with meaningful names instead. But if you do continue to use a tuple, deconstructing it by pattern matching is much clearer than using your `fst4`, `snd4` etc functions.

Again, the code is now shorter and easier to understand, though it might help if we used more meaningful names than `a`, `b`, and `d`.

We can continue in this vein:

```
computeKnapsack []             _          = []
computeKnapsack ((a,b,_,d):xs) weightLeft = (a, b, weight) : (computeKnapsack xs (weightLeft - weight))
  where weight = floor (weightLeft / d) * d
```

Here I've spotted that the same value was being calculated in two different places, and extracted that value into its own named variable. `weight` only needs to be calculated once instead of twice, so `computeKnapsack` is now marginally more efficient. More importantly, I now understand what `computeKnapsack` is doing.

I understand that you're new to Haskell. Please take this as constructive suggestions on how you can write clearer Haskell code.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken the liberty of cleaning up your `computeKnapsack` function so you can more clearly see the problem:

```
computeKnapsack (x:xs) weightLeft =
 let e = (fst4 x, snd4 x, floor (weightLeft / qud4 x) * qud4 x)
  in if length (x:xs) <= 1
     then e
     else e:computeKnapsack xs (weightLeft - floor (weightLeft / qud4 x) * qud4 x)
```

My changes were purely cosmetic.  Even after my changes your `computeKnapsack` function is still broken, a bad algorithm, and bad coding style.

You can see from the rewritten version that your `if` statement has two branches, one returns a tuple, and the other returns a list of tuples.  You can fix it simply by changing the first branch to return a list with a single element:

```
computeKnapsack (x:xs) weightLeft =
 let e = (fst4 x, snd4 x, floor (weightLeft / qud4 x) * qud4 x)
  in if length (x:xs) <= 1
     then [e]
     else e:computeKnapsack xs (weightLeft - floor (weightLeft / qud4 x) * qud4 x)
```

Also, before you submit a third question to StackOverflow, please take the time to complete an introductory tutorial to Haskell like http://learnyouahaskell.com/ which will help fix a lot of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that throws that error in in the then of `fractionalKnapsack`.
In that line you call function `computeKnapsack` with a tuple as the input instead of a `list`.

Comment: Thanks. How can I make sortBy sortFrac (((fst3 x),(snd3 x),(trd3 x),(snd3 x) / (trd3 x)):fracList) a list? I thought that by prepending it to fracList which is a [] it would make it a list ><